# Formik within useFormik - handle array values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using hooks with useFormik in my form. I used  before to handle such cases, but API changed and can't use it with useFormik.
I have simple case when my values are array ['a','b','c'....] and I have inputs one after another. I want to have possibility to delete given input (and item from array) as well as add new.... How to achieve it?
What I've tried so far:

Inside my component I just map by values from array:

```
{values.arrayValues.map((value, index) => (
    <div key={`value_no_${index}`}>
      <FormInput
        label={value}
        name={index}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
            <button
                onClick={() => removeCustomField(index)}
              >
                remove
            </button>
    </div>
  ))}

  const onChange = useCallback(event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const updatedValues = values.arrayValues;
    updatedValues[name] = value;
    setFieldValue('arrayValues', updatedValues);
  }, []);
```

values.arrayValues is my formik array of values, this i what I tried to do onChange. To remove and add I did sth like this:

```
  const removeField = useCallback((index: number) => {
    setFieldValue('arrayValues', values.customFieldsValues.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  }, []);

  const addField = useCallback(() => {
    setFieldValue('arrayValues', [...values.arrayValues, '']);
  }, []);
```

Unfortunately nothing works here properly.
In component with inputs I just use `map` and index is name of input.